# align icons in ionic header

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ion-header

I am trying to have a ion-header where one icon is on left and another on right. my code looks like below

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
      <ion-buttons icon-start>
        <button ion-button icon-only>
          <ion-icon name="contact"></ion-icon>
        </button>

      </ion-buttons>
      <ion-title text-center>about</ion-title>
      <ion-buttons  icon-end>
        <button ion-button icon-only>
          <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </ion-navbar>
  </ion-header>
```

but what is hapenning is that i see it coming in 3 different rows.

Answer (score 0):

ok, you need remove the first `<ion-buttons>` and leave only `<button>` and on the second tag of `<ion-buttons>` change `icon-end` to `end`.

and it should work!!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Since Ionic applies the android/ios standards based on the current platform where the app is running, you need to understand the meaning of the following attributes: `start`, `end`, `left` and `right`.

### **About end/start/left/right**

Using the `start` attribute in the ion-buttons doesn't mean it will be placed to the left, since `start` and `end` follow the **UI pattern for the platform**

So `<ion-buttons start>` would be on the left for ios and be the first button on the right for android.

And `<ion-buttons end>` would be on the right for ios and the last button on the right for android.

So with both `start` or `end` the button will be placed at the right on Android.

If you want to place a button at the left or the right in both platforms, you should use `left` or `right`, since these attributes are provide as a way to over ride that. It's easier to see with a few examples, so please take a look at the following examples.

---

### Example 1: Using `start` and `end`

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-buttons start> <!-- Here we use start -->
        <button ion-button icon-only>
          <ion-icon name="contact"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end> <!-- Here we use end -->
        <button ion-button icon-only>
          <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

The result is:

**iOS**

[image]

**Android**

[image]

---

### Example 2: Using `left` and `right`

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-buttons left> <!-- Here we use left -->
        <button ion-button icon-only>
          <ion-icon name="contact"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons right> <!-- Here we use right -->
        <button ion-button icon-only>
          <ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon>
        </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

The result is:

**iOS**

[image]

**Android**

[image]